# How to call listener for check tree selection dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have one **org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.CheckedTreeSelectionDialog** like below code.

```
final CheckedTreeSelectionDialog checkedTreeSelectionDialog = new
 CheckedTreeSelectionDialog(new Shell(),new ActionLabelProvider(), new
ActionContentProvider());
```

**ActionLabelProvider** implements **org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider** and **ActionContentProvider** implements **org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider**

I have some elements initially selected and some are not in the `CheckedTreeSelectionDialog`.

When dialog is open, if I check the unchecked element, I want to show one message.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `CheckedTreeSelectionDialog` and add **addCheckStateListener**, use the below code.

```
// When user checks a checkbox in the tree

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckStateChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ICheckStateListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.CheckedTreeSelectionDialog;

public class MyCheckedTreeSelectionDialog extends CheckedTreeSelectionDialog {

    public MyCheckedTreeSelectionDialog(Shell parent, ILabelProvider labelProvider, ITreeContentProvider contentProvider) {
        super(parent, labelProvider, contentProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected CheckboxTreeViewer getTreeViewer() {
        CheckboxTreeViewer treeViewer = super.getTreeViewer();
        treeViewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
            public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {

                if (event.getChecked()) {
                    // Given element is checked
                } else {
                    // Given element is un-checked
                   // Your message here
                }
            }
        });

        return treeViewer;
}
```

}

Comment: `getTreeViewer()` is `protected`, not `public` so you have to use a subclass of `CheckedTreeSelectionDialog`.

Comment: I have created one sub class and then also I am not getting the method  `getTreeViewer` where from I am calling the Subclass.Only inside subclass constractor it is available.Please let me know what to do.

Comment: Updated the code, check and verify. You need to override the `getTreeViewer()` method in your subclass.

Comment: I have tried the updated code.It is not coming inside getTreeViwer code at all when checking/selecting.

Comment: Keep debug point inside `checkStateChanged` method and try to debug the code

Comment: I have put debug point but it is not coming this debug point when I check or uncheck.

Comment: Please update your question putting the code you tried with and mention the new problems/observation in the question itself. So somebody else also can look into it.